# Adding a horizontal line at the end of the CV

Tags: header-footer, cv

I am writing a CV in LaTeX, and to do so I downloaded a template from the following link: http://www.mit.edu/~westj/templates/JWest_CV_template.zip.

I am doing pretty good so far but I would like to add a horizontal line at the end of the document. When I try to do so, with `\hrulefill` I obtain the following result.

[image: Result of adding a horizontal line at the bottom.]

I would like the second line to be as the first one (covering all the space, instead of just covering the right-hand side of the paper). I have tried several things like increasing the width with `\hrule`, but I can't make it work because it happens the same but the line is increased to the far right. What can I do to obtain what I need?

P.S.: I posted my problem on the template directly to not show my data and so it is easier to see the `.tex` code which is available to download above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following definitions:

```
\newlength{\Fline}
\setlength{\Fline}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\hoffset\relax}

\nointerlineskip      
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\Fline} 
\nointerlineskip
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it works the way I wanted! Thank you very much.